# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Atom for removing duplicates in a text file?

Tags: text, editor, atom-editor

I have a list of values like so:
CAT 
Dog 
cat 
Cow 
dOg

I want it to have unique entries in quotes like this: 
'CAT' 
'Dog' 
'Cow'

Is there a shortcut in Atom for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not at the moment.  But if you are on a POSIX like system (Linux and MacOS by default, Windows [with some help](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)), you can make use of the atom package '[pipe](https://atom.io/packages/pipe)'

Just mark your text and pipe it through this command:

```
sort -f | uniq -i
```

or with the long options (yes, sort has `-f` and uniq `-i`):

```
sort --ignore-case | uniq --ignore-case
```

On my system that results in:

cat
Cow
dOg

Please note that `uniq` want's its input sorted and similar entries following each other.  Thats why your need to `sort` them first

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quick note: sort --ignore-case | uniq --ignore-case -u gave me all the unique entries.

Comment: BTW: if you want to have it in quotes, sed will help you out, just add this to the chain of pipes:  `| sed "s/.*/'\0'/"`

Comment: Works great! Final answer:  sort --ignore-case | uniq --ignore-case | sed "s/.*/'\0'/".

Comment: Pipe not available in Atom v1.15.0 :(

Comment: @noodl_es I'm not sure what happened between v1.15.0 and v1.26.0 (which I'm running now) but I just installed atom-pipe (same URL that M-x linked to above) and used it. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 5):

atom now has a plugin called `duplicate-removal` which will remove duplicate lines automatically

https://atom.io/packages/duplicate-removal

Comment: duplicate-removal package not available for Atom v1.15.0
neither is permute

Comment: @noodl_es Like with atom-pipe above, I just installed and used duplicate-removal.  I assume there were deprecations (like there still are with permute) which have been fixed since you wrote your comment.

Comment: @noodl_es Annoyingly, the author of the permute package has fixed the deprecations but simply didn't tag her repository so Github isn't showing it and Atom isn't seeing it as a new release. :-/  https://github.com/kristenmills/atom-permute/commit/8a4fecd3984802d9ce3e0df231aab6b3d270ec7c